# UITableView Customize Cell

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am trying ti implement table view cell with customization in that case i need to make a dynamic Heights in specific cell not at all.
show is this possible to define dynamic height for uictableview cell and if yes the how can i perform this operation ?

Thank You.

Comment: post what u try first

Comment: Try to include some code when you ask. It will help others to identify your exact requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this delegate method for UiTableView

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == rownumber) {
        return 150.0;   // Custome size as per requirement
    }

    return 50.0;/// some default size
}



-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;

}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.row == 3) {
        return 150.0;
    }

    return 50.0;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // We are looking for cells with the Cell identifier
    // We should reuse unused cells if there are any
   if(indexpath.row==0 || indexpath.row==1 || indexpath.row==3){
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
   }
   else if(indexpath.row==2){
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // If there is no cell to reuse, create a new one
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }



    return cell;
}
```